# Api calls MEAN4+

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

So i'm working in a mean stack application but i just don't get my api right..
The only thing that works is the GET !
My post and put doesn't seems to work, I think i got my syntax wrong but I just don't find the right one on the internet.

```
//GET 
router.get('/employees', (req, res) => {
    connection((db) => {
        db.collection('employees')        
            .find()
            .toArray()
            .then((employees) => {
                response.data = employees;
                res.json(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                sendError(err, res);
            });
    });
});

// POST

router.post('/employees', (req, res) => {

    const employees = { name: req.body.name, age: req.body.age , wage: req.body.wage , place: req.body.place };
    db.collection('employees').insert(employees, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { 
        res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' }); 
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
      }
    });

  });

//PUT

  router.put('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
    const employee = { name: req.body.name, age: req.body.age , wage: req.body.wage , place: req.body.place };
    db.collection('employees').update(details, employee, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
          res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
      } else {
          res.send(employee);
      } 
    });
  });
```

Comment: can you show the body of the req you're sending with the put and post methods also what response do you get when you try those two methods

Comment: also looks like you dont have db defined in post and put unless your code is missing imports at the top of file that we cant see

Comment: What do you mean with the body from the req ? , and in postman he says that 'db is not defined'

Comment: more than likely you need to wrap your db.collection calls in PUT and POST methods with connection((db)=>{});

Comment: Yes indeed, but why does my Get works ?

Comment: because it has db defined within the GET method's scope

Comment: I tried that already but still got the same error

Comment: did you restart node?

Comment: Is this a private project? Can you share a github repo for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your PUT and POST methods dont have connections to the database established so db.collection is undefined in both

```
router.post('/employees', (req, res) => {

            const employees = { name: req.body.name, age: req.body.age , wage: req.body.wage , place: req.body.place };
    connection((db) => {
            db.collection('employees').insert(employees, (err, result) => {
              if (err) { 
                res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' }); 
              } else {
                res.send(result.ops[0]);
              }
            });
        });
          });

        //PUT

          router.put('/employees/:id', (req, res) => {
            const id = req.params.id;
            const details = { '_id': new ObjectID(id) };
            const employee = { name: req.body.name, age: req.body.age , wage: req.body.wage , place: req.body.place };
            connection((db) => {
            db.collection('employees').update(details, employee, (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                  res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
              } else {
                  res.send(employee);
              } 
            });
    });
          });
```

Comment: Yes thank you, I forgot to restart node --'

Thank you for taking the time !! It's fixed :)

Comment: no problem, glad I could help. Please just mark the question solved thanks.